# How to install erd with cabal install without Could not resolve dependencies error?

Tags: haskell, erd, cabal-install

I'm trying to install **erd** so I can produce some database table entity relationship diagrams using **erd** and **graphviz**.

I have been doing all of the following installs in a Git-Bash command line prompt on a Windows 64 PC.

First I installed Haskell (with cabal included) from [enter link description here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/), then I did a

```
cabal update
```

before attempting the actual install of **erd** with these results

```
$ cabal install erd
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: erd-0.1.3.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of erd-0.1.3.0)
rejecting: base-4.8.2.0/installed-140... (conflict: erd => base==4.7.*)
rejecting: base-4.8.2.0, 4.8.1.0, 4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1,
4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2,
4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint
requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

I saw where a reset sometimes helps

```
rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal
```

But in my case it didn't change the results, I still see "Could not resolve dependencies"

Comment: what version of ghc/cabal are you using - and what version of erd do you want to install, also show the output of `ghc-pkg list`

Comment: I strongly advise you to using [`stack`](http://haskellstack.org) or [`cabal sandboxes`](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html) this makes stuff like this not go away but happen a **lot** easier

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: I'm using cabal version: 'cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library'. I'm new to Hacksell and Cabal, I'm not sure what _stack_ and _sandboxes_ are.

Answer (score 3):

Since `erd` is an executable, I would just install it using `stack`:

Instructions for installing `stack` may be found here:

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md

The run these commands in the shell:

```
cabal get erd-0.1.3.0
cd erd-0.1.3.0
stack init --resolver lts-2.22
stack build
```

The last command report something like:

```
Installing executable(s) in
{some directory}/erd-0.1.3.0/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-2.17/7.8.4/bin
```

We are using lts-2.22 since erd-1.3.0 requires base-4.7.

Comment: FYI, stack unpack will download and unpack a tarball

Comment: Waited about 10 mins while this was executing, only to get an error: `Unable to start C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.8.4\mingw\bin/realgcc.exe (error code: 2)`

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably because `erd` is a really old package and in the package description it says

```
Properties
Version  0.1.3.0
Change log  None available
Dependencies    base (==4.7.*)
              , bytestring (==0.10.*)
              , containers (==0.5.*)
              , graphviz (==2999.*)
              , parsec (==3.1.*)
              , text (==1.*) [details]
```

If you use the latest compiler ghc-7.10 or even ghc-8.0 - the current version of `base` is packaged up with it - which is of today (2016-05-02) `base-4.8` which is incompatible with your project.

So best switch to an older compiler version (ghc-7.8) or try to download the package with `cabal get erd` and adjust the cabal file to `base == 4.8.*` and give it a try.

Comment: I did a `cabal get erd` and some files were updated. I'm not sure where to adjust the cabal file to `base == 4.8.*`. I did find an erd.cabal file but I didn't see a `base ==` in there anywhere. Once I adjust the erd.cabal file then what do I need to do?

Comment: Then you did not look well enough - 6th line from the bottom under 'build-depends'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `cabal install --allow-newer base erd`